# Jquery Slider control for volume

Tags: jquery

I want to create a slider to control the volume of the media player. How to design/create a slider using JQuery.

Geetha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery UI has one built in: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

Comment: how to get the current position value  of the slider?

Comment: Use the value method, http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#option-value. jQuery provides really good documentation, read it.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery slider: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

To get a value, you can use:

```
.slider("value")
```

If you want to get a value when a slider changed:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   change: function(event, ui) {
   // value is ui.value
 }

});
```